# Why is the duplicate of a node's random child null? is there any way to fix or work around it?

Tags: godot, gdscript, godot4

So I took a random node from a parent and duplicated that node. For some reason, the Node3D is a null instance, so I can't really do anything with it.
This is my code:

```
func _ready():
   MoveNode
func RandNode(P):
    P.get_child(randi() % P.get_child_count()).duplicate()
```

But, when I try to move it:

```
func MoveNode()
    var NewNode = RandNode($ParentNodePath)
    NewNode.global_translate = $OtherNodePath.global_translate
```

It gives me an error saying that NewNode is null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You duplicated the node, but forgot to return it:

```
func RandNode(P):
    return P.get_child(randi() % P.get_child_count()).duplicate()
    ^^^^^^
```